# passing the values through parameters in python list function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm starting to learn `list.append` by passing a string to the parameter in the function, However I'm getting an error, how can I solve this issue?

Here's my code:

```py
def add_more(name):
    name.append(5)

name=[1,2,3,4]
print add_more(name)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python print statement “Syntax Error: invalid syntax”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584489/python-print-statement-syntax-error-invalid-syntax)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python)

Comment: Typo error  missing brace bracket `print add_more(name)`. Should be `print(add_more(name))`

Answer (score 0):

While the variable name does get altered as a pass by reference, if you're going to print it out, you'll need to add a return statement to your function

```
def add_more(name):
    name.append(5)
    return name

name=[1,2,3,4] 
print add_more(name)
```